# rsyslog to send ip address rather than hostname

Tags: linux, logging, archlinux, rsyslog

I already setup centralized logging system on my environment but i keep getting hostname from the client rather than ip address
is there a way to receive or send ip instead of hostname?

thanks

Comment: Hello Putofad and welcome ! Can you please give us more context as it is very difficult to give you a solution

Comment: I have 5 servers:
1 centerlized server that i use to collect logs from other servers

5 clients who send logs to the centerlized server.

and when they logs are sent to the centerlized  they are been sent as hostname rather than ip

Answer (score 2):

You would need to define a template on both your remote and central server which uses `fromhost-ip` instead of `fromhost` or `hostname`. This way you will transmit the message with the IP in the message and you will save that information on your central server.

I don't know of any standard templates that use IP address over hostname, as normally a hostname is of more use than an IP address

More info on properties can be found [here](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/properties.html) and templates [here](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/templates.html)